# Parsing Information from redirect URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

I am working with the Hunch API and am trying to allow the user to OAuth with my system. I am directing them to

> http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=12345&next=http://hoosheer.appspot.com/get-recs

from this it allows the user to enter their details and redirects them to my webpage. Once they are redirected to my page, the url has the following information included in it.

```
http://hoosheer.appspot.com/get-recs?auth_token_key=12345abc&user_id=hn_113&next=http://hoosheer.appspot.com/get-recs
```

How can I take the auth_token_key information from this in python?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the parsed querystring parameters out of the request object. You can do that with get() like this:

```
auth_token_key = request.get('auth_token_key')
```

You can read up on this at the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get).

Comment: How can I access the url that I am redirected to in my code. My code is simply 
    url = 'http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/app_id=X&next=/get-recs'
    self.redirect(url)  

Sorry if this is a really obvious answer, I just can't seem to see it ;)

Comment: Create a handler for that URL, just as you would for any other URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://hoosheer.appspot.com/get-recs?auth_token_key=12345abc&user_id=hn_113&next=http://hoosheer.appspot.com/get-recs'
>>> parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['auth_token_key']
['12345abc']
>>>
```